# Convert elements of a matrix to integers

Tags: python, list, matrix, integer

So in Python, I have a matrix as follows:

```
theMatrix = [["String", "0"],["String2", "1"]]
```

And I would like to convert all numbers at index 1 of each list to an integer.

Result:

```
theMatrix = [["String", 0],["String2", 1]]
```

This needs to work for more than just the two lists:

```
eg. theMatrix = [["String", 0],["String2", 1],["String3", 2],["String4", 3]]
```

Comment: What language are you using?  MATLAB?

Comment: Sorry, I am using Python. I knew I missed something!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please elaborate on programming language and will there be more element in the inner list or they are always tuples? u want to convert every integers in string format to int or just the 2nd item in inner list? what is the intention or usage of this data structure. what you may need to consider is a dictionary or hash table. Just give a thought it will fit for ur solution.

For python language and you may have more elements in inner list and always position 1 has to be changed, then the following code may help

```
for innerList in theMatrix:
    if len(innerList) > 1:
        value = int(innerList[1])
        innerList[1] = value if value >= 0 else 0
```

Comment: I am using python, there may be more elements in the inner list, but the index for the string that I want to convert to an integer will always be the same, ie at index 1. I will need to do all the algorithms by hand, so I'm not sure a dictionary would help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
theMatrix = [["String", '0'],["String2", '1'],["String3", '2'],["String4", '3']]
#iterate the list of lists and convert the int string to int.
[[e[0],int(e[-1])] for e in theMatrix]
Out[222]: [['String', 0], ['String2', 1], ['String3', 2], ['String4', 3]]
```